# How to get length of array and do validation accordingly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the validation, where I check length of the array and if array length is 0 then I show alert, but when I click on save button then by default array length shows me as 1.
here is my code:

```
  var skill=[];
  $('#save_skills').on("click",function(){              
            var i = 0;                              
             $('input.skill').each(function(index) {                    
                skill[i] = $(this).val();
                importanceSkill[i] = $('.importance').eq(index).find('option:selected').text();    

                alert(skill.length)

                if(skill.length === 0)
                {                               
                     alert("Please Provide Value");
                     return;                            
                }   
                else
                {   
                    $('#table_display_skills').append('<tr><td>'+ skill[i] +'</td><td>'+ importanceSkill[i] +'</td><td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" onclick="remove_skills()"></span></td></tr>');
                        i = i + 1;                      
                }
            });
```

if I `alert (skill.length)` it shows me as 1, how?
Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is storing 1 element when this line: `skill[i] = $(this).val();` run, even if the value of the `<input>` is empty, your array is storing 1 element which is an empty string.

I'm sure what you want is to check whether each `$('input.skill')` have value or not, so you need to correct your script like this:

change:

`$('input.skill').each(function(index) {`

to

`$('input.skill').each(function(i) {`

then inside that `$('input.skill').each(function(i) {`:

```
if (!$(this).val().length) {
    alert("Please Provide Value");
    return;
}
skill[i] = $(this).val();
$('#table_display_skills').append('<tr><td>'+ skill[i] +'</td><td>'+ importanceSkill[i] +'</td><td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" onclick="remove_skills()"></span></td></tr>');
//i = i + 1; (you won't need this anymore)
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigne  array value before call length show you get 1.

```js
var skill=[];
alert(skill.length);
skill[0] = 'ram'//$(this).val(); // You assigne value here. See a diiff on alert box
alert(skill.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply, but when I print array in alert(in my code), It shows me nothing.

Comment: May be `$(this).val()` return empty so you got nothing. Check for empty before assigne value for array.